# PGSearch adding new column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I added new column "record_created_at" to pg_search_documents. how can i  update this column when record created by mutli-search? i tried to update new column by creating modal and after_create call back. but this call back is not working. can any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can update "record_created_at" field by using `after_commit` callback.
This callback is called after a record has been created, updated, or destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue using rebuild_assets_for_pg_search for specific model.